# CV2, changing codec of a .mp4 file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, codec, opencv

I created a few hundred .mp4 files with the wrong codec, I used

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
```

Instead of,

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
```

Is it possible to change the codec without having to recreate all of the .mp4 files?

Answer (score 1):

Files are compressed using the codec you provided. You cannot change it. You need either to transcode them (from one codec to another: this is a lossy process). You could use ffmpeg library to do so, either by running a batch on the created files or using a python wrapper on ffmpeg

- https://www.ffmpeg.org/
- https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/

It would be easier I guess to re encode the original content with the good codec, no quality loss in that case.